# How to delay the layout update until a popup is closed in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm making a custom MessageDialog. The dialog shows information to the user and waits for button press. I call my dialog asynchronasly with await but my problems is that meanwhile the focus is set to an element in the background (behind the popup). If I use the standart MessageDialog the focus is set again but after the the dialog is closed (The focus is set but the ui is not updated until the dialog is closed). I would like to achieve the same behavior. 
My dialog is based on the InputDialog from WinRT XAML toolkit.
Thanks

Comment: WinRTXamlToolkit adds the AwaitableUI extensions, which give you the ability to `await` `event`s. If you override the OnLayoutUpdated or OnApplyTemplate (I'm not sure which is called first), then you should be able to wait for the event to fire before continuing.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the information. I'll make some tests.

Comment: I found that it is somehow related to the focus. When I set the focus on an control that is outside of the MessageDialog the Focus() method returns true and the element receives GotFocus event. But the control actualy receives the focus after the MessageDialog is closed (at least visibly on the screan). So that means that focus is delayed somehow. If I make other changes in the UI not related to the focus when the MessageBox is opened the layout is updated.